# Generate one list with multiple elements

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to generate a list of 100 triangular numbers. This is what I have for generating 100 triangular numbers. When I run it I get 100 lists, how can I change it to generate one list with 100 elements?

```
def Triangular():
    n=0
    while n<101:
        n=1+n
        triangleNumbers = (n*(n+1))//2
        print ([triangleNumbers])
Triangular()

Desired Result: [1,3,6,..]
Actual Result:
[1]
[3]
[6]
[10]
[15]
[21]
[28]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to difine a list , and use the list metohds to help you, code below should solve your problem.

```
 def Triangular():
        n=0
        result=[]
        while n<101:
            n=1+n
            triangleNumbers = (n*(n+1))//2
            result.append(triangleNumbers)
            print result
    Triangular()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ([triangleNumbers])
```

Look at the above statement.

You are creating a new list rather then adding to a list.

```
>>print (type([triangleNumbers]))
<type 'list'>
```

Instead,

- Initialize an empty list.
- append `triangleNumbers` to the `list` at every iteration.

Sample code:

```
lst=[]
def Triangular():
    n=0
    while n<101:
        n=1+n
        triangleNumbers = (n*(n+1))//2
        lst.append(triangleNumbers)
    print lst

Triangular()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it more pythonic, you could use a list comprehension

```
def Triangular(upto):
    lst = [(n*(n+1))//2 for n in range(1,upto)]
    print lst
```

Personally I'd make the function return the list only, then let the caller print the result

```
def Triangular(upto):
    return [(n*(n+1))//2 for n in range(1,upto)]

lst = Triangular(101)
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this too :

```
lis =[]
for n in range(100):
    lis.append((n*(n+1))//2)

print (lis)
```